# Kali network manager. NetworkManager needs to be running?

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, networkmanager

When opening my network manager on kali i get the message

```
Oops, something has gone wrong. Please contact software vendor.
NetworkManager needs to be running.
```

I've tried

```
service network-manager restart
```

and

```
service network-manager stop
service network-manager start
```

Still get the same error in my network manager.
I have also tried

```
 /etc/init.d/network-manager start
```

Still nothing.
When doing

```
service network-manager status
```

i get

```
Active: active (exited) since Fri 2016-11-11 05:39:00 EST; 10s ago
Process: 1744 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/network-manager stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
process: 1747 execStart=/etc/init.d/network-manager start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

I am running the latest kali 2016.2.

Comment: `failed to enable unit: unit file /etc/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service is masked.`

Comment: @GAD3R When running `systemctl enable network-manager.service' i get `network-manager.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-syvs-install.`

Comment: @GAD3R `executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable network-manager.` Still doesn't fix my issue.

Comment: @GAD3R After running the `unmask` command i got the output `Removed /etc/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service`

Comment: @GAD3R first i get `failed to start NetworkManager.service: Unit NetworkManager.service not found` and `failed to enable unit: No such file or directory`

Comment: @GAD3R thet is no NetworkManager in /lib/systemd/system